# Kitchen end panel - Need to adjust door?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I'm planning on adding an end panel to my kitchen base cabinet.

My question is... With the door of my cabinet currently flush with the side, will adding an end panel mean that I have to adjust my door and move it inward? And if so, by how much?

I haven't been able to find anything online with regards to standards/diagrams etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End panels usually fit to the front and back edge of the cabinet.

If you have "full overlay" cabinets the door fits just shy of the outer edge.

The hinges can be adjusted to move the door in all directions. Most times only a millimeter or so is needed.

The screw marked in blue moves the door to the left or right of the cabinet face. ( this is the screw you would adjust if you need clearance from the panel)

The screws marked in green when loosened will allow the door to move up and down.

The screw in red, if loosened will allow the door to be moved out away from the front edge or closer to the edge.

(Note that there are many styles of hinges and yours may be different from the one I posted here, but the general idea is the same.)

[image]

Comment: Ah cheers. Yes I have these sorts of hinges. Was just a case of if and how much I'd need to adjust the door as it's a self-built unit.